# dispatcher.forward() produces HTTP 500

Tags: java, http, tomcat, servlets, relative-path

Consider the hierarchy :

[image]

I moved my JSPs from `WEB-INF` to the `src` folder .However when I try to `dispatcher.forward()` , I get :

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
    controller.LoginPage.doPost(LoginPage.java:214)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.50 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.50
```

The specified exception occurs in the lines :

```
 String addressPath = "/../view/admin/adminPage.jsp";
 RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(addressPath);
 dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

How can I fix the path ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that your JSP is in a source folder seems to indicate that it will be placed in

```
/WEB-INF/classes/view/admin/
```

Which is really not where

```
String addressPath = "/../view/admin/adminPage.jsp";
```

is pointing it to.

`getRequestDispatcher` returns `null` if the Servlet container cannot return a `RequestDispatcher` for the given path.

JSPs shouldn't really be under `/WEB-INF/classes`. Put them in a dedicated folder like `/WEB-INF/jsp/view` and access them there.

You could then access it with

```
String addressPath = "/WEB-INF/jsp/view/admin/adminPage.jsp";
```

Comment: I put the files in `WEB-INF` , and `WEB-INF` in `src` , but the path `"/WEB-INF/jsp/view/admin/adminPage.jsp"` doesn't work .

Comment: @ron No, `src` is a source folder under Eclipse. With a `Dynamic Web Project`, Eclipse takes everything under there and puts it in `WEB-INF/classes`. Put the JSPs in `Web Content`, under `WEB-INF`.

Comment: You mean there is no way accessing the JSPs from within `src` ?

Comment: @ron Technically, I think you should be able to get it with `/WEB-INF/classes/view/admin/adminPage.jsp`.

Comment: @ron You're welcome, but please don't do that. `WEB-INF/classes` is more targeted for Java `.class` files and other classpath resources. JSPs should have their own directory even though they are eventually compiled.